# Is there a way to get a notification e-mail when a question gets answered?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Is there a way to get a notification e-mail when a question gets answered? Because it's not always easy to keep track of all the forums you are on, especially if answers only come like days after you posed the question.

Comment: Related older posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/add-notify-option and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/automatic-notifications

Comment: Did you check the checkbox "Email me my unread inbox messages"
among [preferences on your profile page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/preferences)? There are options weekly/daily/once in 3 hours to choose from.

Comment: It was checked, I must have missed a lot of these e-mails somehow. Thx.

Comment: So the option exists (see comments), but I guess the problem is that somehow if you visit this site during a day and don't look at your inbox (which I forget sometimes), u don't get an e-mail notification no more for answers of that day if your notification interval is set to daily mail. Could that be correct? So you don't always get all new answers mailed if u already visited the site that day or clicked on your inbox icon that day?